# server.R needs to be touched for execution

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

My Shiny app is supposed to read a directory and capture all rds files. It is running fine. But when a new rds file is coming into directory from where app suppose to read, it's not able to read new file. When I touch server.R then app is able to capture new file as well.

So long story in short, whenever a new file is coming into directory, I need to to touch server.R file to work as latest content. I am not making any changes in server.R. To execute successfully I need to run "touch server.R". has someone seen this before?

I am not able to understand, server.R needs any change in time stamp to run successfully.

Thanks!
Tinku

@ MrFlick - No I haven't hard coded anything in server.R file. Actually same code is working on other server. I just copied the same program from test to qa box and not it changed the behavior. If I touched the server.R file and refresh the browser then it is working fine. Very starange for me!

@jdharrison - Thanks for your suggestion. But this (my existing server.R) code is running fine on dev server but when I moved to QA, then it not running as expected. I am surprised, that what touch or any non significant change in server.R is enabling it to run fine for one time.

Actually server.R code is reading the .RDS files from the directory and displaying in drop down list. it is working fine on dev server. But on QA server, if I am deleting or creating any new .RDS file then it's not displaying in drop down list automatically, until I touch the server.R file.

Comment: Are your rds files loaded in the `server.R` file? You probably have a code path that only runs once during the lifetime of the server and touching the file essentially restarts the server and re-runs that code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `reactivePoll`to periodically check the directory you are interested in. In this example an `actionButton` allows the user to add a file to a test directory. The test directory is polled every second by the app and a table with file info is displayed:

```
library(shiny)
dir.create('test', showWarnings = FALSE)
write(1:3, 'test/dumfile.txt')
write(1:3, 'test/dumfile2.txt')
readTimestamp <- function() Sys.time()
valueFunc <- function() {
  print(readTimestamp())
  out <- lapply(list.files('test', full.names = TRUE), file.info)
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)
}
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    actionButton("addFile", "Add a file!"),
    tableOutput('myTable')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      if(input$addFile > 0){
        write(1:3, tempfile('file', 'test', '.txt'))
      }
    })
    dirData <- reactivePoll(1000, session, readTimestamp, valueFunc)
    output$myTable <- renderTable({
      myData <- dirData()
      myData
    })
  }
))
```

[image]